# HTMLCollection elements lose attributes when shown individually, but are okay when the entire collection gets shown

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTMLCollection of elements. Its elements have three attributes (*class*, *value* and *disabled*). When I `console.log` the entire HTMLCollection (as in `console.log(collect)`) all of the elements show up as having every one of these three attributes:

[image]

When I console log **one individual** item from the collection (as in `console.log(collect[2])`, two of the attributes disappear:

[image]

This is how I generate the collection and how I log it:

```
var collection = selects[0].children;
console.log(collection);
console.log(collection[3]);
```

This is exactly what's shown when I run this code:

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce with Firefox 63.0 (Linux) neither Chromium... What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Zim Firefox 63.0. The code is in a WordPress theme, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have no idea what are the technical consequences of being in Wordpress, but I doubt there can be any regarding the browser console. You may try to reproduce your problem in a short and self-contained example which gets rid of any third party library and see if it still occurs...